# Channel not getting created in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, peer

I am trying to create a channel named `channel1` from peer using the following command:

```
peer channel create -o hr.debut.com:7050 -c channel1 -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls --cafile '/home/akshay/fabric-material/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/debut.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.debut.com-cert.pem'
```

but the thing is channel is not getting created. I am getting the following error from peer:

```
2018-04-16 17:16:42.742 IST [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1
```

The orderer on the other machine shows the following logs:

```
2018-04-16 17:24:39.411 IST [orderer/common/server] Deliver -> DEBU 389 Starting new Deliver handler
2018-04-16 17:24:39.411 IST [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 38a Starting new deliver loop for 192.168.0.146:46254
2018-04-16 17:24:39.411 IST [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 38b Attempting to read seek info message from 192.168.0.146:46254
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [orderer/common/server] Broadcast -> DEBU 38c Starting new Broadcast handler
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 38d Starting new broadcast loop for 192.168.0.146:46256
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> DEBU 38e [channel: channel1] Broadcast is processing config update message from 192.168.0.146:46256
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [orderer/common/msgprocessor] ProcessConfigUpdateMsg -> DEBU 38f Processing config update message for channel channel1
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 390 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 391 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 392 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 393 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 394 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/DebutInfotechPvtLtdOrderer/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 395 0xc42000e398 gate 1523879679413974329 evaluation starts
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 396 0xc42000e398 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-04-16 17:24:39.413 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 397 0xc42000e398 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 398 0xc42000e398 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected DebutOrdererMSP, got AxisMSP)
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 399 0xc42000e398 principal evaluation fails
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 39a 0xc42000e398 gate 1523879679413974329 evaluation fails
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 39b Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/DebutInfotechPvtLtdOrderer/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 39c == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/DebutInfotechPvtLtdOrderer/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] func1 -> DEBU 39d Evaluation Failed: Only 0 policies were satisfied, but needed 1 of [ DebutInfotechPvtLtdOrderer.Writers ]
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 39e Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 39f == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Orderer/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3a0 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3a1 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3a2 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/DebutInfotechPvtLtd/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 3a3 0xc42000e3a0 gate 1523879679414123667 evaluation starts
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3a4 0xc42000e3a0 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3a5 0xc42000e3a0 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3a6 0xc42000e3a0 identity 0 does not satisfy principal: the identity is a member of a different MSP (expected DebutMSP, got AxisMSP)
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3a7 0xc42000e3a0 principal evaluation fails
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 3a8 0xc42000e3a0 gate 1523879679414123667 evaluation fails
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3a9 Signature set did not satisfy policy /Channel/Application/DebutInfotechPvtLtd/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3aa == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/DebutInfotechPvtLtd/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3ab == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/AxisBankPvtLtd/Writers ==
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 3ac 0xc42000e3a8 gate 1523879679414218441 evaluation starts
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3ad 0xc42000e3a8 signed by 0 principal evaluation starts (used [false])
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3ae 0xc42000e3a8 processing identity 0 with bytes of 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
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [msp] SatisfiesPrincipal -> DEBU 3af Checking if identity satisfies MEMBER role for AxisMSP
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [msp] Validate -> DEBU 3b0 MSP AxisMSP validating identity
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [msp] getCertificationChain -> DEBU 3b1 MSP AxisMSP getting certification chain
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3b2 0xc42000e3a8 principal matched by identity 0
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [msp/identity] Verify -> DEBU 3b3 Verify: digest = 00000000  cf 80 17 5f bf 33 05 ed  7b b9 fa 29 9d ba 75 19  |..._.3..{..)..u.|
00000010  40 62 19 00 60 24 55 14  e4 e7 ae 68 b8 a9 89 60  |@b..`$U....h...`|
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [msp/identity] Verify -> DEBU 3b4 Verify: sig = 00000000  30 45 02 21 00 b2 24 0d  0e 7f 19 4b 57 5a f9 ac  |0E.!..$....KWZ..|
00000010  9d 0f 5a 07 36 03 03 a7  8c 4b 14 3f 98 6b e9 da  |..Z.6....K.?.k..|
00000020  5c 0f ed 04 3c 02 20 4b  eb 32 4a ce a4 b5 b8 85  |\...<. K.2J.....|
00000030  d8 f0 ce cc d8 73 4e bb  55 61 38 07 4b fb 98 1d  |.....sN.Ua8.K...|
00000040  fb c1 14 03 9f 44 46                              |.....DF|
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func2 -> DEBU 3b5 0xc42000e3a8 principal evaluation succeeds for identity 0
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [cauthdsl] func1 -> DEBU 3b6 0xc42000e3a8 gate 1523879679414218441 evaluation succeeds
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3b7 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/AxisBankPvtLtd/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3b8 == Done Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/AxisBankPvtLtd/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3b9 Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Application/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3ba == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3bb Signature set satisfies policy /Channel/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 3bc == Done Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Writers
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 3bd Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 3be Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Application
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 3bf Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Application/AxisBankPvtLtd
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 3c0 Adding to config map: [Group]  /Channel/Application/DebutInfotechPvtLtd
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [common/configtx] addToMap -> DEBU 3c1 Adding to config map: [Value]  /Channel/Consortium
2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 3c2 [channel: channel1] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.0.146:46256 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1
2018-04-16 17:24:39.415 IST [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 3c3 Closing Broadcast stream
2018-04-16 17:24:39.416 IST [common/deliver] Handle -> WARN 3c4 Error reading from 192.168.0.146:46254: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2018-04-16 17:24:39.416 IST [orderer/common/server] func1 -> DEBU 3c5 Closing Deliver stream
```

**Note:** Some people suggested that the channel is already created. I could not find any channel1.block file on my system. I do not know if there are any cached being written by peer or orderer on my system which I need to delete in order to clean up the stuff. I am running this network using 4 kafka and 1 zookeeper. I am not running any docker container so please do not suggest to bring down docker and remove the containers. I am running this network on 3 systems.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> 2018-04-16 17:24:39.414 IST [orderer/common/broadcast] Handle -> WARN 3c2 [channel: channel1] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.0.146:46256 because of error: error authorizing update: error validating ReadSet: readset expected key [Group]  /Channel/Application at version 0, but got version 1

does indicate that the channel is already created.

If you need to retrieve the genesis block for your already created channel you may simply run:

```
peer channel fetch 0 channel1.block.pb -c channel1 -o hr.debut.com:7050 --tls --cafile '/home/akshay/fabric-material/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/debut.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.debut.com-cert.pem'
```

This will fetch the genesis block and write it to `channel1.block`.